# A graph that is tough but not Hamiltonian.

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

A graph G is **tough** if the number of $c(G-s) \le |S|$ for all $S \in V(G)$.

And I read that every tough graph is Hamiltonian, but the other way is not true. I was wondering if there is an example of a graph that is tough but is not Hamiltonian.

I think Petersen's graph is one example, but are there any other such graphs?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean $S \subseteq V(G)$. Also I think you have got the statement beginning "And I read" the wrong way round. You ought to be able to find an answer by following up the pointers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_toughness).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Chvátal's original paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X73901386) defining toughness gives an example of a $7$-vertex graph which is tough but not Hamiltonian:

[image]

This is easy to verify, since a Hamiltonian cycle would have to use both edges out of each of the vertices with degree $2$, which includes three edges out of the center vertex.